# R diagrammeR : How to make a cluster in a dynamic way?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a diagram where nodes are grouped by cluster. I am able to make it using grViz but I don't know how to make it using dynamic functions of DiagrammeR
1st code is using grViz to show what I would like to build
2nd code is what I started to do using dynamic functions. Any idea how to create clusters and to link them in a global diagram?

1st code

```
library("DiagrammeR")

grViz("
  digraph G {

    subgraph cluster1 {
      'c'
      'd' -> 'e'
    }

    subgraph cluster2 {
      'a'
      'b'
    }

    subgraph cluster3 {
      'f' -> 'a'
      'f' -> 'c'
    }
  }
")
```

2nd code (beginning of it)

```
ndf1 <-
  create_node_df(
    n = 3,
    label = c('c','d','e'))

edf1 <- 
  create_edge_df(
    from = c(2),
    to   = c(3))

grf1 <- 
  create_graph(
    nodes_df = ndf1,
    edges_df = edf1)
render_graph(graph = grf1)
```

I am wondering if there are functions like combine allowing to create such boxes...

Answer (score 0):

This feature was added, but still isn't documented except in the [github issues page](https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/257).

The example from the issues page

```
nodeDF <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), 
                    label = c("a","b","c"),
                    cluster = c(NA,"data","data.sub"))
edgeDF <- data.frame(from = c(1,2),
                    to = c(3,3))

create_graph() %>%
  add_nodes_from_table(nodeDF, label_col = label) %>%
  add_edges_from_table(edgeDF, from, to, id_external) %>%
  add_global_graph_attrs("layout", "dot", "graph") %>%
  render_graph()
```

may, at sometime in the future allow the creation of nested clusters, but with the current CRAN version (1.0.6.1) it creates two sister clusters instead.

**edit:** While not part of diagrammeR, on the [issue page listed above](https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/257), there is now working code to make nested clusters.